# C# working with listview's

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm new to C#. I'm attempting to populate a listview with data and here's what I've come up with so far

```
ListViewItem LItem = new ListViewItem();
LItem.Content = new string[] { drow["FP1_NAME"].ToString(), "test" };
ProductsListView.Items.Add(LItem);
```

When I run this, `'String[] Array'` is shown, but not the actual data, e.g., "test". I've scoured google and stack overflow here but haven't quite found my answer.

Using Visual Studio 2013. Thanks

Comment: Visual studio is an editor and can run many versions of .net which can be created by other versions of visual studio; in effect it means little. Specify in the tags what version of .Net being used and whether this is Asp.net, wpf or winforms...for they all have listboxes.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly.

Comment: My apologies for the noobness - I edited my question tags to reflect my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the quick input. Everyone telling me to check which version of .NET and WPF vs. WinForms allowed me to tailor my Google Search a bit better and I came up with an answer.

Instead of adding individual items, I binded my dataset directly to the listview via `ProductsListView.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView;`

I skipped using the drow variable which was a referencing a row in the dataset. Afterwards I modified the XAML to add the following

```
        <ListView x:Name="ProductsListView" Height="319" Width="509">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView> // *** the new columns below are what I needed! ***
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FP1_NAME}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Short Desc"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FP1_SHORT_DESC}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I actually saw a few very similar questions, which I'm suspecting are from new C#/Visual Studio users like me so I'll leave my answer up (unless it's best to take it down). Sorry for leaving out details in the original post that would have led to a quicker solution. I guess my issue was not knowing how to ask/search for the *RIGHT* question. Thanks

Comment: Good job figuring it out. Since I didn't know what `drow` was, I was working up an example that used a collection and a new class. lol. It is much easier to use the dataset directly for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to add a string as a listitem, the Items.Add method allows you to add it directly:

```
ProductsListView.Items.Add("test");
```

There are other overrides to the add method that allow you to indicate a key, and icon image index, etc...